# Need to boot MacBook Pro into USB recovery mode

Tags: usb, password, recovery

I am trying to help someone recover data from a non-functional MBP (it was dropped).

I have the internal drive mounted in a sled and connected to another MBP via USB. I can boot off of the drive holding the Option key and get the login screen but, as the password is unknown, I need to boot the drive into the external drive's recovery partition, open up the Terminal and execute the `resetpassword` command.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to boot from it to recover data - in fact it's probably far easier if you don't.

If you have the drive mounted from an external USB, you can just Get Info & check 'ignore ownership' - that will work unless the drive is encrypted.

If it is, you need the password.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you switch HDDs with the one on the sled and have it put on the functional MBP and just access the recovery partition from there. :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the drive was encrypted with File Vault. Thankfully I was able to "hack" the password from hints that the person I am helping gave me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot up in Single User Mode off the USB.  Hold <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> while turning on your Mac
2. At the command prompt, execute `mount -uw /`
3. Execute `resetpassword`